# Unit Testing with the Entity Framework change tracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

How do I test/simulate/use the change tracker of Entity Framework when testing?

For my example below I would like to verify that the fake list of LogEntries starts out one way and by the time the `SaveChanges` is called, is modified to match my expectations.

I was initially thinking of something like exposing a public property in the `FakeLogRepo` that would show me the fake list of LogEntries so that I can easily compare the before/after, but I still can't figure out how to update it without passing in something from the `LogInteraction` (since in production Entity Framework handles that through its change tracker).

For a simplified example of what I have:

```
public class LogInteraction : ILogInteraction
{
    private readonly ILogRepo _logRepo;

    public LogInteraction(ILogRepo logRepo)
    {
        _logRepo = logRepo;
    }

    public void UpdateLog(IEnumerable<Detail> details)
    {
        foreach (var detail in details)
        {
            var record = _logRepo.GetById(detail.Id);
            record.Status = detail.Status;
            record.Message = detail.Message;
        }

        _logRepo.UpdateLogEntries();
    }
}

public class LogRepo : ILogRepo
{
    private readonly LogContext _logContext;

    public LogRepo()
    {
        _logContext = new LogContext();
    }

    public LogEntry GetById(int id)
    {
        return _logContext.LogEntries.Single(r => r.Id == id);
    }

    public void UpdateLogEntries()
    {
        _logContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class LogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<LogEntry> LogEntries {get; set;}
}
```

When in production the `_logContext.SaveChanges()` does what it's supposed to and update the changed records through the magic of Entity Framework's change tracker. However in testing I'm not using a DB, I'd like to use a fake list of LogEntry to simulate this. Since `List` doesn't have a change tracker, I thought about having it inherit from `IObservableCollection` but couldn't figure out how to use it without a substantial refactor of my code. In fact any idea I have involves a substantial rewrite of my code just to work with a test (and will leave unused/extraneous code in production).

Am I barking up the wrong tree and need to change my mindset overall or am I just not seeing something that I'm close to?

Comment: What you want to test exactly?

Comment: @Emre, doh, that would help wouldn't it. Let me edit.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see much value in writing unit tests for code like this, especially since you know it already works.  This code is mostly  uninteresting boilerplate.

Comment: @RobertHarvey well I'm making changes in the LogInteraction, so I'd like to verify that the changes made match my expectations. I'm not interested in testing the LogRepo, that's just a wrapper for a Context which has been tested to heck and back so no need for me to do that.

Comment: You can mock your db context and db set. After that you can setup your db set with fake log entries and make an update on that data. And compare initial data with updated one. Is not that help you in your case?
Look at my another answer for mocking db context : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983787/how-do-i-unit-test-a-void-function-that-inserts-into-the-database-and-saves/50001500#50001500

Comment: You can verify those expectations by checking the `details` collection you passed in.

Comment: Mocking EF DbSet can get complex and has limitations. Since you are querying to get a record first, then editing it, you'll have to mock not just the DbSet, but the litany of IQueryable's as well. If you wish to continue down this route I'd suggest following [Microsoft's Definition and Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx) of how to accomplish this (assuming you aren't already...). However, in memory tests like this have limitations as their article defines. IMHO, you own the database. Make a test database definition and use integration tests instead.